# V4L2 image size problems

Tags: video, webcam, video-capture, v4l2

I found a very estrange problem using V4L2 and some Logitech webcam. Setting height = 320, width = 240 and format I420, the image size must be 115200 bytes, but querying through V4L2 give me 29390 bytes how image size.

I think to force the buffer sizes with the correct size, but seems that the driver don't support 115200 bytes how buffer size using height = 320 and width = 240, so I can't capture correctly.

Someone could help me?

Thanks

Comment: How do you make sure that your changes are successful? Before you query buffer size, check for the current settings to see if the image format is indeed 320x240 I420.

Comment: Hello vbence, I was checking the current settings, and everything was ok I420, 320, 240, but, the driver didn't tell me that the video was compressed in mpeg format, so when I read the 29390 bytes, decompress it and play the images uncompressed I could see the images correctly. Driver fail, because the format was mpeg and not I420

Comment: just curious, wat fourcc code did you see your PIXFMT was?...